# Solving $(x^m+y^m-z^m)^n=(x^n+y^n-z^n)^m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $m$ and $n$ are distinct positive integers then does the equation

$(x^m+y^m-z^m)^n=(x^n+y^n-z^n)^m$ $\space$has any solution , for $x,y,z$ , in positive integers with $x,y,z$ all not equal ?

Comment: Just to clarify:  Does the problem asks to find an $m$ and $n$ for any $x,y,z$?

Comment: @chubakueno: No , the question asks to find $x,y,z$ ,with $x,y,z,$ not all equal , for given $m$ and $n$ ; clearly as the question reads "solution , for $x,y,z$ , in positive integers with $x,y,z$ all not equal"

Comment: For example, if $m$ and $n$ are even, $(x,y,z)=(-1,0,1)$ is a solution. Is this problem yours or is it from a problem set?

Comment: @ chubakueno:- I said positive $x,y,z$ , remember?

Comment: Oh! My bad. And where did you got this problem?

Comment: @chubakueno:- A friend of mine was actually thinking  about it . It might have some standard source but I am not aware of it.